# Aligning text to left and also right within Bootstrap accordion

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have an accordion in Bootstrap going, but I want text on the left side, but also the right side, right by the arrow which controls the collapsing:

[image: How justification is misaligned]

I have:

```html
<div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="accordion-tracks">
 <div class="accordion-item">
  <h2 class="accordion-header" id="heading-1">

   <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-1">
     <div class="d-flex justify-content-between w-100">
        <div>1. The Eater Of Dreams</div>
        <div style="padding-right: 10px;">0:52</div>
     </div>
   </button>

 </h2>
....
```

I am not sure if doing this in a `button` is even recommended. I have tried with `span` and `float-start` and `float-end` too but that does not seem to work.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting off with the example from the [Bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/accordion/), you only need to do two things:

1. Add a couple of container tags inside the button tag to create the two columns.
2. Add a class to the button and and style it as a grid.

You will end up with 3 columns inside the grid, one for the title, one for the time, and one for the arrow (which is a pseudo element)

```css
button.acc-btn {
  /* create a grid */
  display: grid;
  /* create colums. 1fr means use available space */
  grid-template-columns: 1fr max-content max-content;
  align-items: center;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
      <button class="acc-btn accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                <span class="title">
                    1. The Eater Of Dreams
                </span>
                <span class="time">
                    0:52
                </span>
            </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is shown by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and
        hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingTwo">
      <button class="acc-btn accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                <span class="title">
                    1. The Eater Of Dreams
                </span>
                <span class="time">
                    0:52
                </span>
            </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is shown by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and
        hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked great and when sized down. I just took out the `align-items: center;`. Very neat trick...Thank you!